# Download Themes From LocalHost WordPress Site

Tags: themes

I am wanting to download themes from my localhost install of Wordpress.  My issue is that anytime I click download, I get a pop-up asking me for Connection Information.

I tried to input localhost and my Wordpress username and password, but it will not download.  What step have I missed here?

**edit**
And I am running localhost on a Ubuntu laptop with LAMP installed.

**edit 2**
This is an image of the request screen that I get, where I input localhost and my valid username and password
[image: Image1]

And this is an image of the error I receive when I try those reds
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your local FTP service is not running. You can verify this by trying to connect to the local FTP server at the command prompt:

```
ftp localserver
```

and it will ask for your credentials.

Also possible is that 'localserver' is not being resolved locally. You can check that with a command

```
nslookup localserver
```

And seeing if it gives you your servers' IP address.

But this is not a WP Development question. Ask the googles/bings/ducks for help with enabling/starting your local FTP service.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info!  I thought it was a WP issue, I didn't realize that it was FTP related.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering your system username and password. It sounds like you don't have permissions set correctly (or rather, in LAMP they are but not for what you are trying to do with WordPress). Also, you might have a look at the [FS_METHOD constant](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) and try setting it in to `ftpext` (along with the other required settings) in wp-config.php.

If these things don't work, consider editing your question to include a screen shot of the username and password window you are seeing so that we know exactly which screen is blocking you.